# Negative lookahead for expression that is also included in search

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

I need to find and replace disabled testNG tests tags, while also adding the new annotation "disabledTests" to the same test.

Here is the input data set:

```
    @Test(groups={"endtoend"}, enabled = false)
    @Test(enabled = false, groups={"endtoend"} )
    @Test(groups = {"integration"}, enabled = false) laksdflas
    @Test(groups={"integration","honor"}, enabled = false)
    @Test(enabled=false){}
    @Test(groups={"integration","honor"}, enabled = true)
    @Test(groups={"integration"})
```

Using Notepad++ here is the find regex:

```
((\(|enabled\s*=\s*false).*(groups\s*=\s*)(\{"|")(.*)("\}|").*(enabled\s*=\s*false|)\)|\(enabled\s*=\s*false\))
```

Here is the replace regex:

```
\(enabled=true, groups={"disabledtests","\5"}\)
```

Here is the output using the aforementioned find and replace regexes:

```
@Test(enabled=true, groups={"disabledtests","endtoend"})
@Test(enabled=true, groups={"disabledtests","endtoend"})
@Test(enabled=true, groups={"disabledtests","integration"}) laksdflas
@Test(enabled=true, groups={"disabledtests","integration","honor"})
@Test(enabled=true, groups={"disabledtests",""}){}
@Test(enabled=true, groups={"disabledtests","integration","honor"})
@Test(enabled=true, groups={"disabledtests","integration"})
```

The extra blank annotation in the fifth example is not an issue.  The problem concerns the last two lines being replaced:

```
@Test(groups={"integration","honor"}, enabled = true)
@Test(groups={"integration"})
```

Notice in the input data set these tests did not have the "enabled=false" tag.  I need my find regex to exclude these cases, meaning those lines should not be returned in the search.

Should negative lookahead be used for these cases?  If so, may I have some hints?

Alternatively, I am open to better find and replace regexes than what I'm using.

Here is the desired output:

```
@Test(enabled=true, groups={"disabledtests","endtoend"})
@Test(enabled=true, groups={"disabledtests","endtoend"})
@Test(enabled=true, groups={"disabledtests","integration"}) laksdflas
@Test(enabled=true, groups={"disabledtests","integration","honor"})
@Test(enabled=true, groups={"disabledtests",""}){}
@Test(groups={"integration","honor"}, enabled = true)
@Test(groups={"integration"})
```

Comment: For updating nested structured data, you might want to consider building a simple parser.  In any case, can you edit your question to clearly show the current input and what desired output you want?

Comment: Ok, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `(?=.*enabled\s*=\s*false)` to your regex (after the `(`) seems to work. After the first `(`, this does lookahead on the current line to check if the line contains some form of 'enabled=false' before proceeding.

`((?=.*enabled\s*=\s*false)(\(|enabled\s*=\s*false).*(groups\s*=\s*)(\{"|")(.*)("\}|").*(enabled\s*=\s*false|)\)|\(enabled\s*=\s*false\))`

Answer (score 1):

A TestNG way to do what you want, without code modification, is by using [IAnnotationTransformer](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers):

```
public class MyAnnotationTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

  @Override
  public void transform(ITest annotation, Class<?> testClass,
      Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {

      if (annotation.getEnabled() = false) {
          annotation.setEnabled(true);
          String[] groups = annotation.getGroups();
          String[] newGroups = new String[groups.length + 1];
          newGroups[0] = "disabledtests";
          // copy groups into newGroups
          annotation.setGroups(newGroups);
      }
  }
}
```